How to disable VSCode warnings from Go src packages?
I'm just starting my journey with Go and wonder why I have warnings about Go source code in the IDE.

Is there an easy way to disable these? Why is VScode even reporting them?
I'm using the default Go extension and 1.22.3 Go version.

Could you share your code? I think it will be better to fix it rather than disable it.

Did you read my post? The warnings are from the actual go src code, these aren't warnings from my code.

Oops sorry. I misunderstood your post.

You should not need to disable anything, something is not right here. Is staticcheck up to date (along with other tools)?

@JimB thank you, you were right - I had some very old version of staticcheck.
After re-installing go, it works without problems. If you want to add answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

I had some very old version of staticcheck (present in go/bin folder).
After re-installing Go and VScode Go extension, it works without problems.
Shout to JimB for giving me a hint.
